# Как загрузить папку с файлами?

Tags: php

Можно ли как то выбрать для загрузки **папку**(например документы и внутри 5 файлов) , а не 1 файл в папке (нужно переместить или скопировать папку с файлами). Если архив, то я не знаю можно ли его потом как то разархивировать.

```html
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="files" value="Выбрать"><br><br>
    <button>Загрузить</button>
</form>
```

Comment: вопросы к браузеру а не к пхп. Папку вы браузеру не скормите. лишь все файлы пачкой отправить можете. Архив сделать тоже можете, и разархивировать проблем обычно нет, если это zip обычный.

Comment: Тогда лучше архивом. Спасибо. Почитаю как разархивировать на php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Загрузить просто папку никак не получится. Можно запаковать папку в архив, загрузить на сервер и после загрузки распаковать. Для распаковки можно использовать класс ZipArchive в РНР, например.

Либо можно поставить у тега input атрибут multiple="true", и загружать несколько файлов. Только тогда и обработку загрузки придется переделать, т.к. передаваемый массив изменит свою структуру.

Comment: Если можно ссылку почитать как разархивировать после загрузки

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/class.ziparchive.php